# NestJS TypeORM Postg res a NULL value violates NOT NULL constraint of column "id" in relation QueryFailedError

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am having an issue when I try to insert an element:

```
a NULL value violates NOT NULL constraint of column 'id' in relation 'users' QueryFailedError
```

I try to insert an object with all the fields but it doesn't work

```
{
    "id":5,
    "firstname": "test3",
    "lastname": "test3",
    "passwd":"test3",
    "email": "test3",
    "user_role": "test3"
}
```

user.entity.ts:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('users')
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id!: number;

  @Column()
  firstname: string;

  @Column()
  lastname: string;

  @Column()
  passwd: string;

  @Column()
  email:string;

  @Column()
  user_role:string;
  
}
```

user.service.ts:

```
...
  async createUser(user: User): Promise<User> {
    const userSaved = await this.usersRepository.save(user);
    userSaved.passwd="***";
    console.log('userSaved ', userSaved);
    return userSaved;
  }
...
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';

@Module({
  imports: [AuthModule, UsersModule, TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    username: 'postgres',
    password: 'postgres',
    database: 'todo',
    schema: 'public',
    autoLoadEntities: true,
    synchronize: false,
  })],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Table users:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.users
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    firstname character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    lastname character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    passwd character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    user_role character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    email character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I've got thos error on the logs of my server. I do not know what to do
Any idea?

Comment: Is it possible to empty the users' table and try it? Also, since you've defined id as `PrimaryGeneratedColumn` column, you don't need to provide `id` in the input data. This will be automatically generated.